# React Jest Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite

Tags: javascript, jestjs, hook, use-effect

I don´t understand why I'm having error **"Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."** when I run my test, this is where I make the request:

```js
// usePokemon.js

export const usePokemon = (pokemonName) => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, SetIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPokemon() {
      SetIsLoading(true);
      try {
        let namePokemon = pokemonName.toLocaleLowerCase();
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${namePokemon}`
        );
        const json = await response.json();
        setPokemon(json);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }
      SetIsLoading(false);
    }
    fetchPokemon();
  }, [pokemonName]);

  return { pokemon, error, isLoading };
};
```

this is my Hook Test:

```js
//usePokemon.test.js

import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { usePokemon } from "./usePokemon";

const getControlledPromise = () => {
  let deferred;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred = { resolve, reject };
  });
  return { deferred, promise };
};

describe("Success test", () => {

    test("handles loading state correctly", async () => {
      const { deferred, promise } = getControlledPromise();
  
      global.fetch = jest.fn(() => promise);
  
      const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(usePokemon);
  
      expect(result.current.isLoading).toBe(true);
      deferred.resolve();
  
      await waitForNextUpdate();
      expect(result.current.isLoading).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

  31 |       global.fetch = jest.fn(() => promise);
  32 |   
> 33 |       const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(usePokemon);
     |                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would spy on the method that's responsible for making a request used in the component:

Example in component:

```
const { value, isFetching, params } = ExampleModel.methodName({
 startTime,
 endTime,
 someId
})
```

Example in test:

```
jest.spyOn(ExampleModel.methodName).mockReturnValue({
 isFetching: false,
 params: undefined,
 value: []
})
```